# How do I deploy a program to Solana - Solana/Rust

Tags: solana-program, error

I am attempting to run the HelloWorld Solana program. I have cloned this repo. I have started the project with

```
solana-test-validator
```

I ran npm install and then was able to build the rust project with

```
npm run build:program-rust
```

I can see the .so file in the directory /dist/program/helloworld.so. When I try to deploy the program to Solana, I run

```
solana program deploy dist/program/helloworld.so
```

And here is the error I get

```
Error: Dynamic program error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Although I have confirmed it is there, it cannot locate the file. I tried the entire path, but I still receive the same issue. The libs have been cleaned and reinstalled, however, that didn't help.

What should I attempt next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things to make sure of:

1. The localhost (as opposed to devnet) is set via `solana config set --url localhost`
2. You have generated a new keypair `solana-keygen new`

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be Because your terminal's current working directory  is not the parent directory of the dist Folder.